# Assigning result of async method to a variable

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm looking at the "good" example in [this scenario](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md#timer-callbacks), specifically assigning the result of an async method to a variable. (In this case it's a [discard variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) but it works the same if I just do `var x =`).

```
public void Heartbeat(object state)
{
    // Discard the result
    _ = DoAsyncPing();
}

private async Task DoAsyncPing()
{
    await _client.GetAsync("http://mybackend/api/ping");
}
```

In trying this myself, I notice that if I remove the `_` variable, I get compiler warnings saying "this call is not awaited". Why does assigning the result make a difference to how the method is called? Is there an implicit `await` somewhere?

Comment: I have my doubts about the 'good' scenario, but maybe I miss something. Would be interesting to see what happens with an exception from DoAsyncPing().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `_` keyword its assigning the output of `DoAsyncPing()` to `_` as a `Task`. In that case there is no execution yet its just a task.

Without the `_`= then the function is called and the compiler is warning you that the call is not awaited. So the first method is assignment and the second is execution

Comment: Ah this took me a minute to parse as one long sentence, but I get it now, thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Edited the answer to be with shorter sentences :)

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup. So if I assigned it to `var x =` or whatever, that variable would have a task that would never complete?

Comment: Why would there be no execution in the 2nd snippet?  It looks a lot like the async void sample. No place to catch the exception (or the success). But the Ping is executed.

Comment: @What do you mean by second snippet?

Comment: Second peace of the question or answer?\

Answer (score 1):

About your code, `_` contains Task.

**If you don't put await execution of existing method will continue regardless of your async method's completion status**

if you need to wait for some async operation to be completed before continuing the current method you should put `await`

let's take an example.

1. You want some counter data from a website you a method for that (E.g `public async Task<int> GetCounter()`)

Here GetCounter is an async method but you should wait for it before continuing. hence put await.

2. You want to push +1 counter to the same website now you don't want to know if the website received that or not at that time you can ignore putting await.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke an `Async` method you will have to return `Task` instead of `void`.

Since you're trying to call `DoAsyncPing()` from `Heartbeat`:

1.- Convert `void Heartbeat(object state)` to `async Task HeartbeatAsync(object state)`.

- Adding the `async` statement will allow you to `await` inside it.
- [Convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/implementing-the-task-based-asynchronous-pattern) says you might need to call `awaitable/async` methods
  `MethodNameAsync()`.

2.- Covering previous requirement, you now would be able to call `DoAsyncPing()` (I suggest renaming it to `DoPingAsync()` this way:

```
public async Task Heartbeat(object state)
{
    // Discard the result
    _ = await DoAsyncPing();
}
```

Give a try to [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) Stephen's Cleary post where explains how to work with `async` and `await` and why you should avoid `async void`. In a nutshell: just use `async void` on events and when you call an `async` method, everything inside it has to return at least `Task`.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Hey thanks, but this isn't my code, it's from one of the ASP.NET core architects illustrating a scenario. I think the assumption here is that `Heartbeat` can't be made async, I'm wondering why the variable assignment makes a difference.